# How to allow yup object to take in undefined with MUI?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, yup, react-typescript

Although my Form has clearly declared that the key is optional, my input does not seem to accept undefined as a value here, my input keeps returning me the error :

bonusPercentage must be a `number` type, but the final value was: `NaN` (cast from the value `""`).

here is my schema

```
  const schema = yup.object().shape({
    bonusPercentage: yup.number().optional()
  })
```

and I have declared it's initial value as such :

```
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    control,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm<QueryingPromotionForm>({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    mode: 'onChange',
    defaultValues: {
      bonusPercentage: undefined
    }
  })
```

and this is how I'm registering the values into yup form.

```
<Box display={'flex'} flexDirection={'column'}>
            <Typography
              component={'span'}
              paddingBottom='8px'
              sx={{ color: '#7b7b7b' }}
            >
              Bonus Percentage
            </Typography>
            <TextField
              sx={textFieldStyle}
              label='Bonus Percentage (%)'
              size='small'
              fullWidth
              {...register('bonusPercentage')}
              error={Boolean(errors.bonusPercentage)}
            />
            <ErrorMessage
              errorMessage={errors.bonusPercentage?.message as string}
            />
          </Box>
```

I tried adding type='number' to the textfield too but it just keeps throwing me the same error over and over again. How can I let it accept undefined without any inputs in it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  const schema = yup.object().shape({
    bonusPercentage: yup.number().notRequired()
  })
```

[This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#schemanotrequired-schema)
is a shortcut for schema.nullable().optional();

[.nullable()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#schemanullable-schema) indicates that null is a valid value for the schema. Without nullable() null is treated as a different type.

[.optional()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#schemaoptional-schema) allows undefined values for the given type.